# How to use sequelize in node.js express with controllers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

at first a general question: Should I use one sequelize object (instance) for all requests if I use raw sql requests or one object per Session/Request? Can I use the same model-object (instance) for all requests. (Thread safety?)

Where should I place the sequelize object if I use express crontroler/router model? As a global in the server file?

Thanks

Comment: I'd provide some code samples, if you have them. It'll help people get context around what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then "one sequelize object (instance)" means eg:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.database,
  config.username,
  config.password,
  config
);
```

If so, it's fine to reuse that one `sequelize` variable. There's no need to create a separate instance per request. Likewise for models - you don't need to create new ones per-request. Javascript doesn't have threads, so thread safety isn't a concern here.

Express / sequelize aren't prescriptive about file structure, so where you place the sequelize object is up to you. If your app is simple, then it's fine to start by putting it in the one server file. But, as you're app grows, you'll definitely want to extract sequelize out into it's own file like `sequelize.js`, or even several files - one per model type - eg. blogs, categories, etc, with an index file that groups them - eg:

```
/models/index.js
/models/blogs.js
/models/categories.js
```